# After upgrading to PHP 7 in session out problem occurs

Tags: php, session, php-7

I have upgraded my PHP version to alpha 7.0 in my live server which is under Netfirms. After that session out problem occurs within a short period of time( hardly 2 min). This problem doesn't happen in 'CPanel'. Only netfirms server the session out happens.

Comment: Dont you tested on local before uploaded on live server !!!

Comment: Everything is working fine with local .

Comment: why alpha 7.0? and not stable versions?

Comment: in my testing servr alpha 7 is the available version. Stable version also same problem happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the session out problem after updating the session path to 'null' in config.php under condignater application folder.